# phpBB3 changing attachments save destination

Tags: php, uploading, phpbb3, attachment

I'm currently doing some work with phpBB on an Amazon Web Services setup. This will allow the site to scale if required as we're expecting heavy load. Anyway, one of the problems with phpBB is that by default it only allows attachments to be saved to its internal file structure.

What I need to do is alter where the files are stored and loaded from so that the site can scale correctly. It also means I can use the cache provided by Cloudfront for the attachments.

I've done a search of Google but haven't found any documentation of anyone changing where attachments get saved to.

If anyone has any knowledge on this then I'd be greatly to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount your cloud storage location to /files/ (default phpbb3 attachment location). Then your attachments will be served from /files/ as normal, which is hosted on your storage provider location.